# Flutter eye dropper

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to find eye dropper for flutter or implement one.  Can anybody help me with that?

I want to tap an image and get the colour of tapped area.  Similar to an eyedropper for android.[link](https://github.com/Madrapps/EyeDropper)

```
final View targetView = findViewById(R.id.targerView);
   // Any view from which you want to pick the color
   new EyeDropper(targetView, new ColorSelectionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onColorSelected(@ColorInt int color) {
         // color is the color selected when you touch the targetView
         (findViewById(R.id.colorSlot)).setBackgroundColor(color);
      }
  });
```

I just need something that allows me to pick a colour from an image just by tapping an area of an image and get the colour of that area.

Comment: if you're just in search of a color picker lib check on dart.dev for some like this one
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_colorpicker

Comment: if you're searching more for how to change the background of a container you can do that with a color variable and the setState function that any stateful widget has

Comment: please extend your question if it isn't one of the above

Comment: I just need something that allow me pick a color from an image just by tapping a area of an image and get the color of that area

Comment: i found  it finaly myself  here is the link https://gist.github.com/roipeker/9315aa25301f5c0362caaebd15876c2f   and here is youtube demo thanks you very mutch bro https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJyRH4_pY8I

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin for it. https://pub.dev/packages/cyclop it has the option you required.